# Android Support Design Library: Toolbar collapses in 4.1

Tags: android, xamarin, androiddesignsupport, android-snackbar

After updating Android Support Design Library version, I found this bug.
In place of empty area, toolbar should have been displayed.

When I scroll up and down, the toolbar does not appear, blank area replaces the toolbar.

Please tell me what is the problem ?

[image: Normal, start state]

[image: Bug after SnackBar dissmiss]

> `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>       android:id="@+id/main_content"
>       android:layout_width="match_parent"
>       android:layout_height="match_parent">
>       <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
>           android:id="@+id/appbar"
>           android:layout_width="match_parent"
>           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>           android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
>           <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>               android:id="@+id/toolbar"
>               android:layout_width="match_parent"
>               android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
>               android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
>               app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
>               app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
>       </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
>       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
>           android:id="@+id/TaskTypes"
>           android:scrollbars="vertical"
>           android:layout_width="match_parent"
>           android:layout_height="match_parent"
>           app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
>   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>`

Comment: Try to remove app:layout_scrollFlags from toolbar. And check..

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem. The toolbar is now fixed. I need: to scroll up when he disappeared , while scrolling down appeared

Comment: you want it to appear when scroll down, and disappear when scroll up. Is that right?

Comment: @Darpan yes is right